# How to select the second or third row of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query:

```
SELECT TOP 6 
    NoMachine, COUNT(NoMachine) AS Calls 
FROM 
    DT 
GROUP BY 
    NoMachine 
ORDER BY 
    Calls DESC;
```

Of these 6 records, I want to select every one, the first, the second, the third, etc.

What is the easiest method to do this? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: If you only want the 1st 3 of the `TOP 6`, why not just use `TOP 3`? Also, jsut incase no one *has* reminded you, SQL Server 2008(R2) is now out of support; so you really want to look at Upgrade Paths.

Comment: I need info of the most used machines, the first 6. One by one. And I cannot upgrade the SQL Server on my job's server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from 
(SELECT  NoMachine,
 COUNT(*) AS Calls,
 row_number()over(order by  Calls DESC) rn
 FROM DT GROUP BY NoMachine 
) a where rn in (2,3)
```

Comment: I cant understand this code, a lot of syntax error.

Comment: @RobertoLopez  some typo was there updated answer check now

Comment: I edited your code, and now work fine for me, Thank you very much!

Comment: This would be a much better answer if the code posted was actually valid. The concept is fine but the code as posted simply won't work. Just change the first line to "with cte as" and this would be workable.